Limit of Python call stack variables in Visual Studio Code
I'm using Visual Studio Code to debug a Python program with a deep, recursive call stack.
The debugger shows the entire call stack, but it seems that the "Variables" view, showing the local variables at each place in the call stack, only gets updated when I select one of the few first or last of the stack frames.
If I select one in the middle, the "Variables" view does not get updated at all.
Is there any setting (in the IDE, the debugger, Python, ...) that would increase the range where variables are shown?

if it looks like a bug, create an issue at the Python extension
